# Disable BlockUI for certain ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, blockui

I am using the brilliant BlockUI, and have set it up using the default

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Which is great - except when I add a autocomplete element on the page, and then the blockUI kicks in as soon as the user starts typing.  Rather than explicitly set what ajax calls to launch the block UI can anyone think of a way to disable blockUI for certain ajax functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var dontBlock = false;

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    if(!dontBlock)
        $.blockUI();
}).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

// And in the ajax methods (to be excluded), set dontBlock accordingly

$('#autocomplete').keydown(function(){
    dontBlock = true;
    $.ajax({
        // url, data etc.
        success: function(){ dontBlock = false; }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 24):

In jQuery an ajax call accepts different **settings** A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. All settings are optional.

Now here we have the following:

*settings name*: **global**,*Type*: **Boolean**, *Default*: **true**

***Description:***
Whether to trigger global Ajax event handlers for this request. The default is true. Set to false to prevent the global handlers like ajaxStart or ajaxStop from being triggered. This can be used to control various Ajax Events.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        success: function(data) {
          $('.result').html(data);
          alert('Load was performed.');
        }
});
```

Above example will stop execution of any ajax start or ajax stop events like blockUI.

Comment: Awesome! Learned this today... :)